# Calculate the highest palindrome that is the product of two 3-digit numbers

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm stuck on Euler#4 which is to calculate the highest palindrome number by product of two 3-digit numbers. The answer I'm getting is always 0.  Evidently help is required.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,h=0,m=0,p=0;

    clrscr();

    for(i=100;i<1000;i++)
    {
        for(j=100;j<1000;j++)
        {
            p=i*j;
            h=p/100000;
            m=p%10;

            if(h==m)
            {
                h=(p/10000)%10;
                m=(p/10)%10;

                if(h==m)
                {
                    h=(p/1000)%10;
                    m=(p%1000)/100;

                    if(h==p)
                    {
                        printf("%d\n",p);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this is against the [Project Euler policy](http://projecteuler.net/about).

Answer (score 1):

Its wrong to do this, but still dont make it a habit. I think one can solve first 50 question with ease.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int is_palindromic(unsigned int n);

int main(void)
{
  unsigned int i, j, max = 0;
  for (i = 100; i <= 999; i++) {
    for (j = 100; j <= 999; j++) {
      unsigned int p = i*j;
      if (is_palindromic(p) && p > max) {
        max = p;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("%u\n", max);
  return 0;
}

int is_palindromic(unsigned int n)
{
  unsigned int reversed = 0, t = n;

  while (t) {
    reversed = 10*reversed + (t % 10);
    t /= 10;
  }
  return reversed == n;
}
```

Comment: Test `p>max` as the *first* expression in your `if` condition. No need to crunch the number unless the product is larger than your max.

Comment: @WhozCraig are you the creator of craigs list?